# Signal Smoothness & Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: smooth-manifolds, signal-processing, lipschitz-functions, wavelets

I have a signal $s(t)$ defined over $t\in[0, T]$ that is assumed to be smooth up to order $d > 1$, i.e., its $d$th order derivative is continuous (and bounded by say $\epsilon$). Then I sample this signal with a sampling rate of $f_s$ (a sampling time $T_s = 1/f_s$) to obtain $s[n]=s(nT_s)$.

1- I'm looking for a way to express this problem and relate the order $d$ derivative bounds on $s(t)$ ($\epsilon$ or other bounds on its lower order derivatives, if needed) to the concept of local or global Lipschitz continuity. The relation seems trivial for $d=1$, by definition. How about $d>1$? Does there exist a thing like "higher-order Lipschitz continuity"?

2- How can I relate the first, second, or higher order sample difference operators such as $D_1(s[n]) = s[n] - s[n-1]$ or $D_2(s[n]) = s[n] - 2s[n-1] + s[n-2]$, etc. to the concept of Lipschitz continuity?

(sorry if the problem is not rigorously stated. I'm not a mathematician; I have a signal processing background)

Thanks!

Comment: I think I found the answer to my first question: The notion of order $d$ regularity is closely related to the concept of "wavelet zoom", described in Mallat's Wavelet Tour textbook (chapter 6). Any further comments and discussions, especially on the second question are very much appreciated.